# use javascript value in html erb

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use a JavaScript variable in an HTML erb, using `<% %>` tags. `query[i]` is something I have in loop I am trying to call:

```
 <%= Table.update('query[i]')%>;
```

How can I use `query[i]` from JavaScript for the actual value?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. `erb` runs on the server to generate the HTML, which is then sent to the client, where the Javascript runs. By the time the Javascript variable is available, `erb` has already executed, and we're not even on the same machine anymore!

It looks as though you want Javascript code to supply a value which is then used as an argument to a database call. You'll have to do this via a post-back; i.e., the Javascript can make an AJAX call, a new `erb` could generate the new HTML fragment, and then the Javascript can receive it and plug it into the page.

[Here's](http://ruby-on-rails-tutorials.blogspot.com/2010/11/rails3-ajax-tricks-with-javascript-erb.html) the first link I got when I googled "`erb` AJAX".

Comment: Can i set a separate ruby variable with the javascript variable and then use that variable each time  in the loop within the <% %> tags?

Comment: I don't think you read my answer carefully enough. When the Javascript code actually runs, the `erb` process has already completed, and *you're on a completely separate machine*. `erb` runs in your web server, and Javascript runs on the user's desktop. While `erb` is running, the Javascript variable *doesn't exist yet.*

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: Man, where do they get these ideas from? :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683059/how-to-call-javascript-method-in-asp-net-web-application/8683102#8683102

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev .. i don't think this questions is as silly as the one you've posted.. newbies surely have some doubts. Everyone is not intellectual enough.. Thats y there are these forums...

Comment: I couldn't really give a concise example, as it would involve both a client-side piece and a server-side piece; using AJAX is straightforward, but there are a lot of details to get right. I'll add a link to an AJAX tutorial, though.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev -- I think a lot of people get to this point and are a little confused; it's because frameworks are so sophisticated these days that folks can build very complex applications without needing to know how everything works under the hood. No worries, though -- eventually they'll learn, and as user1120180 says, that's why we have forums!

Comment: I am using  
    <%= remote_function :url => Table.update , :with => "'query1=' +#{$query_1}" %>
And in the model, I am using params[:query1] to get the parameter. But  I am getting 
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:---------> error. Could you trace where I'm wrong?