# How to call a java script function in class of our asp.net webpage using c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have used jQuery in my website. I have a navigation bar in my header. When user clicks any link given in my menu bar. It calls my javascript function..and a dialog box appears having a form. For example I have a form say "Add Country". When user clicks the link "Add country"

A form appears in a dialog box. And then user will be able to add country in the given form.

Now i have a gridview in my page..where im managing my data. My country table has 3 coloumns. Coutry Code, Country Name, Description. I have bound country table as sql datasource with that gridview. I have added a asp button as a template item in that gridview as well. All i want to do is..When user clicks the edit button of the particular row in my grid view..i would get the countryID of that row. And i want to call that country FORM again..where user will be able to edit. How can i call my java script function in c# code so that i would be able to call that form again ? I m relatively a new programmer. Anmy detailed guidance will be highly appreciated.

Lets suppose i have :

```
protected void EditSeriesButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    int countryID =Convert.ToInt32(CountryGridView.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

    //Here i have got the id of that row. Now i want to call the function of my
    //javascript so that i can call my country form.
    //Just please guide me how to call javascript function here to open my 
    // dialog box.
    //i will do rest of the things.
}
```

Please  help me as soon as possible!!

Regards,

Comment: I am using .net 4 framework using Visual Studio 2010..!!

Comment: does this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693601/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-c-sharp

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683059/how-to-call-javascript-method-in-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gridview's rowdatabound event to add a onclick attribute to that button to call the javascript function:

```
protected void CountryGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int countryID = Convert.ToInt32(CountryGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);
        Button btnButton = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnName");
        btnButton.OnClientClick = "return Dosomething('"+countryID+"');";
    }
}
```